# Comparing proportions: Is this data able to justify the statement "the more educated you are, the more likely you are to be unemployed"?

Tags: bayesian, proportion, percentage

Hopefully they can help me, I have a question regarding: http://www.oecd.org/edu/Mexico-EAG2014-Country-Note.pdf

The table on page 12 shows the percentages of unemployment by level of education

- Below upper secondary 4%
- Upper secondary and post-secondary non-tertiary 4%
- Tertiary 5%

The percentage grows with the level of education which seems to imply that higher education is higher unemployment ... but ... if we consider the proportions each level of education with respect to the total, this trend, in my opinion, is reversed.

What is the percentage of each educational level with respect to the entire Mexican population? (The correspondence with the Ibero information is far from perfect, since it is the year 2014 and not 2012, but I think it serves to illustrate the point below https://www.scribd.com/document/351836199/Observatory-of-Wages-of-the-University-Ibero-American-Puebla-present-its-report-2017)

Percentages of population by level of education

- Below upper secondary 77.7%
- Upper secondary and post-secondary non-tertiary 10.4%
- Tertiary 11.8%

Let's do the calculations:

- 4% of 77.7% is 3.1% of the total
- 4% of 10.4% is 0.4% of the total
- 5% of 11.8% is 0.5% of the total

Thus, the segment of the population with the highest level of unemployment in absolute terms (3.1%) is that of people with below upper secondary education. The higher education, the less unemployment, in the order of 6 times difference (0.5% to 3.1%). This is in direct opposition to the initial notion that in Mexico, the more education, the greater the unemployment.

Is there any error in my calculations? Or, effectively, once the effect of greater unemployment on higher education is controlled for the base proportion of each population is reversed?

I know that the real world is way more complex than this. What I want to know is: *if I **only** had the information I shared here, what would be the best strategy to avoid unemployment: more education or less education?*

Answer (score 3):

You've calculated the proportion of people who are unemployed who are from different educational backgrounds, and the trend in that is the reverse of the trend seen when looking at the proportion of people of each educational group who are unemployed.

The probability that someone is unemployed, given they have a given education level does not equal the probability that they have a certain education level given they are unemployed. Which one you want to use of depends on what you want to do.

If the proportion of people who are unemployed at each educational level is:
Below upper secondary 4%
Upper secondary and post-secondary non-tertiary 4%
Tertiary 5%

Those with tertiary educations are more likely they are to be unemployed.

Which means that, if you picked someone who has a below upper secondary education, it is less likely that they will be unemployed than if you picked someone with a tertiary education.

But, just picking at unemployed person at random it's much more likely that they have a Below upper secondary education than a higher level of education. There is no paradox here, they can both be true.

Comment: But then, if you had to use this data to recommend more education (or not) what would you do? Is the answer given the current data simply "inconclusive"?

Comment: In order to give a well reasoned argument as to whether education is likely to improve a particular person's outlook, you need to consider much more than a 1% difference in unemployment. I doubt that people earn the same amount for example. Just because someone is currently unemployed doesn't mean their long term prospects are worse - the currently unemployed person with a bachelor's degree will (likely) have a much higher expected lifetime earning than the current employed person with a job. Plus, the economic situation is likely to change, and the value of education may increase, and etc.

Comment: Thanks, I know that the real world is way more complex than this. What I want to know is, if you only had the information I shared here, what would be the best strategy to avoid unemployment: more education or less education?

Comment: If that's the only info you have, given that an the proportion of people that are unemployed goes up at the level of tertiary education, if you want to minimise the likelihood of unemployment you would not suggest that someone got a tertiary degree. They are more likely to be unemployed than someone who has not got a tertiary degree.

Comment: There's a hidden variable here: people naturally seek jobs that match their interests and education level. A person with a tertiary education *could* find work as a driver or at macdonald's if they wanted, but they typically decide that they want more, and so they will turn down those job offers.